# How to update constraints using Masonry DSL?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating my auto layout constraints in code, using [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry), in `updateConstraints`:

I get the following in the console log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8eabc684e0  Demo.View1:0x7f8eabc34680.top == Demo.View2:0x7f8eabc3ef20.bottom + 10>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f8eabc39420 Demo.View1:0x7f8eabc34680.top == Demo.View2:0x7f8eabc3ef20.bottom + 40>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f8eabc39420 Demo.View1:0x7f8eabc34680.top == Demo.View2:0x7f8eabc3ef20.bottom + 40>
```

Why it didn't update the constraint?

**Update:**

BTW: I'm using the storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good advice from the error message here

> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

and helpfully printed out

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8eabc684e0  Demo.View1:0x7f8eabc34680.top == Demo.View2:0x7f8eabc3ef20.bottom + 10>"
"<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7f8eabc39420 Demo.View1:0x7f8eabc34680.top == Demo.View2:0x7f8eabc3ef20.bottom + 40>"
```

Note the similarity between the two constraints and object references

The top of `view1` should be below the bottom of `view2` by 10 or 40 . Cant be both so which one ? As you are using `Masonry` I suspect its the `MASLayoutConstraint` one you want.

Figure out where the `NSLayoutConstraint` is coming from. Its not an autoresizing one as they have squiggles in them. So either you put it there in your code or it came from a XIB/Storyboard.

You can use the regex find in Xcode to make it easier if its the former. I might try this.

Hit the disclosure by the search icon. You can insert various patterns.

[image]

I might use this as a starter

[image]

Comment: the NSLayoutConstraint (10) is from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us your constraints so it's hard to tell what is wrong.

I am not sure why but you can't update constraints with relative values like multipliedBy. What you can do is update constraints to a constant. And the constant you can calculate relative to screen size. Like so:

```
 _height_y = -self.view.frame.size.height*0.25;
[_phoneField updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.baseline.equalTo(self.view.centerY).with.offset(_height_y);
}];
```